# vue-toastr doesn't work when I am using this in inertia.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am creating a page using Inertia.js. When I added vue-toastr in Vue template file, it doesn't work. I have no idea how to fix it. Please suggests me

This is app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'

import Toastr from 'vue-toastr'
Vue.use(Toastr);

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props }) {
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App, props),
    }).$mount(el)
  },
})
```

This is vue template file

```
<script>
 import Master from './Layout/Master';
  export default{
    name:"Home",
    created(){
      this.$toastr.s("success","it is working");
    },
  components:{Master}
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Which files I need to show you

Answer (score 0):

```
use 

the import Toastr from 'vue-toastr' 

directly on your vue instance not in app.js like this : 

<script>
 import Master from './Layout/Master';
 import Toastr from 'vue-toastr'

  export default{
    name:"Home",
    data()
   {
       return 
          {
            toastr: Toastr
           }
      }
,
    created(){
      this.$toastr.s("success","it is working");
    },
  components:{Master}
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).